# Trying to get non repeating numbers by using nested loop..(2-D array)

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to figure out a way that I can insert random numbers into a 2-d array that is 5x5. I am working on a bingo game so it anyone could help me I would be greatly appreciative. I am fairly new to Java, so any help would be good. Thanks.

Consider:

```
boolean matchFound;  // used to track when a repeat is found
int rand; // temporarily store the random number before putting it into the array to check if it's a repeat

Random rn = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 25 ; i++) {
    rand = rn.nextInt(15) + 1;
    matchFound = false;  // assume that the number generated is not a repeat
    for (int x = 0; x <= 5; x++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 5 ; ++j){
            if (rand == b[x][j]) {  // check if the number just generated is a repeat
                matchFound = true;  // if it is, set the boolean to True and use that after the loop
            }           
            if (matchFound == true) { // if the last number is a repeat, then
                i = i - 1;  // reduce the loop counter by 1 to go back to that place for the new number
            } else {
                b[i][j] = rand;  // the number was not repeated so insert it.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello,  it's not applicable to add from 1 to 15 in your array, as you need 25 different elements, so you will end up with infinite loop

Comment: Ah yes that would explain that, but if i wanted to do the first column int the 2-d array[1][5] to be 1-15, the second, 16-30..etc. Up to 75, for a bingo game. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. It works perfectly but i want to understand what the switch and case breaks do. Just so I don't feel like im just compiling code that i don't know how it works. So if you could do a brief explanation it would be great! Thanks again!

Comment: happy for that man, I just modified the code again, and removed this switch to make the code more compact... the switch statement just like if else statement which examines its input and if it matches the case, then it do some action and go out the switch statment

Comment: Alright, you have been very helpful! Thank you.

Comment: I would like to add an action listener to an array of button that have each random number set as their text. Is there a way that i could just do one action listener for all of the buttons? (the action listener will change the Jbutton's foreground)

Comment: yes you can do that; you need to add a unique tag for each button, and register all buttons with a single listener, and then differentiate between buttons using the tag attribute when the callback of the listener is triggers (this is a typical case of using switch statement)

Comment: `B.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { //Action Listener when pressing "Generate Card"
            private boolean right = false;
            
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (!right) {
                    B.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
                } else if (right) {
                    yay.setVisible(false);
                }
                right = !right;
            }
        });`

Comment: This is what i have and I have an array of `JButton B[][] = new JButton[5][5];` and i am very new to java so i do not know what you mean by adding a unique tag for each button..

Comment: you can use `myButton.setName("btn1");` for certain tag

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As in bingo game, You need to track the column number to get the right range boundary of each column (min & max values in below code).

and for each iteration in the outer loop of column values these values will change accordingly

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] b = new int[5][5]; // 5x5 grid

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { // loop for columns

        int min = i * 15 + 1;
        int max = (i + 1) * 15;

        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) { // loop for rows
            int rand;

            do {
                rand = getRandom(min, max); // generate random int between min & max values
            } while (isMatch(rand, b));

            b[j][i] = rand;
        }
    }
    /* print array values */
    for (int[] x : b)
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));

}

/* return true if num is in the array b */
private static boolean isMatch(int num, int b[][]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            if (num == b[i][j]) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/* return integer number between min & max inclusive */
public static int getRandom(int min, int max) {
    return (int) ((Math.random() * (max + 1 - min)) + min);
}
```

**Output**

```
[14, 22, 37, 57, 62]
[15, 20, 45, 55, 63]
[6, 29, 38, 52, 69]
[11, 30, 34, 59, 74]
[4, 16, 36, 54, 67]
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend treating it like a bingo game - where you have a set of numbers, randomize them, and the 'pick' numbers for the board. I believe bingo ranges from 1-75? but you could change that. And then just pick the first 25 numbers from your ArrayList, they are sure to be random and not repeated this way.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<Integer> bingo = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int[][] b = new int[5][5];

        // create a list in order
        for (int i = 1; i <= 75; i++) {
          bingo.add(i);
        }

        Collections.shuffle(bingo); // randomize

        // Add to the board
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
          for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            b[i][j] = bingo.remove(0); // remove the first item in the shuffled list
          }
        }

        System.out.print(Arrays.deepToString(b));
    }
}
```